# MYSQL distinct column row pair query

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb

Imagine a table of contacts, where the same contact has multiple entries, but with differing data. How would one go about selecting this data for review? Unfortunately, a merge of sorts would be disagreeable as there may exist visually identifiable erroneous data that is not currently envisaged to be automatically processed.

```
FName         LName           Email           Phone
Heywood       Yapinchme                       555-555-555
Heywood       Yapinchme       hy@moes.com               
Seymour       Butz            sb@moes.com   
Seymour       Butz                            555-555-556
Seymour       Butz            
Hughe         Jass            hj@moes.com     555-555-557
Amanda        Hugginkiss      ah@moes.com
```

I would like to see just the duplicates of the first two columns where more than one entry exists. i.e.

```
FName         LName           Email           Phone
Heywood       Yapinchme                       555-555-555
Heywood       Yapinchme       hy@moes.com               
Seymour       Butz            sb@moes.com   
Seymour       Butz                            555-555-556
Seymour       Butz
```

The next step of review is in the blue ether. Currently a little over a million rows, Bart has been busy. But beefy servers and this isn't regular operation but a one off to deal with data migration, so can be slightly gash.

I have tried a bit with `SELECT DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY` but it seems to just return on of each contact.

Comment: I'm using php, mysql or mariadb. any solution welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use aggregation to identify the duplicates:

```
SELECT FName, LName
FROM tablename
GROUP BY FName, LName
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

and if you want all the rows of the duplicates:

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
WHERE (FName, LName) IN (
  SELECT FName, LName
  FROM tablename
  GROUP BY FName, LName
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
```

If your MySql/MariaDB version supports window functions:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (
  SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY FName, LName) counter
  FROM tablename
) t
WHERE t.counter > 1
```

Comment: Perfect thank you so much. A small blessing upon your help, and something to light your life perhaps; May flowers always line your path and sunshine light your day.
May songbirds serenade you every step along the way.
May a rainbow run beside you in a sky that’s always blue.
And may happiness fill your heart each day your whole life through.